Are my CNN loss and performance curves valid, or are they showing under or overfitting?
Thanks in advance for any help offered.
I am using a Keras CNN to perform binary classification (credit card transactions fraud vs non-fraud). Below is my results for 100 epochs.
It feels odd that the val performance (I'm using f1 score) instantly jumps to 87/88%, then shows no further improvement. I was expecting a standard curve where performance is poor in the first few epochs, then improves quickly over time, before settling down. Training and val curves are close together by the end, so I don't think this shows obvious under or overfitting. Is this a valid result or am I doing something obvious wrong?
Information that might help

Model code is below
dataset is very unbalanced (only 500 frauds in 280k transactions)
No resampling for this test, but I don't think it is relevant for my question.



   model = Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(32, 2, activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2))

    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(64, 2, activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))

    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5))

    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))


It doesn't really indicate anything wrong, it might simply be that the problem it relatively easy for the model to learn and few samples are needed. In turn, most of the learning happens within the first epoch which you don't see since you're only logging the metrics at the end of each epoch.
